# Winforms Designer errors when changing accessibility of a control

Tags: c#, winforms, designer

I decided to change a listBox1 item in my form1 designer to public static instead of private to access it on another form. And once I had done that It had errored and not allowed me to changed things on the form itself and just tells me this error at the top

```
  The variable 'listBox1' is either undeclared or was never assigned.
```

The error is shown on the following line

```
this.panel1.Controls.Add(listBox1);
```

My Designer for my form below:

```
  namespace Mercury.Forms
  {
partial class Inside
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
        this.label1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.label2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        Inside.listBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ListBox();
        this.label3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
        this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
        this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        this.pictureBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.pictureBox1.Image = global::Mercury.Properties.Resources.pooltablegodass_500x750;
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 11);
        this.pictureBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 4, 3, 4);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(54, 48);
        this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Click);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this.label1.AutoSize = true;
        this.label1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
        this.label1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(74, 15);
        this.label1.Name = "label1";
        this.label1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(82, 20);
        this.label1.TabIndex = 1;
        this.label1.Text = "Ash Smith";
        this.label1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label1_Click);
        // 
        // label2
        // 
        this.label2.AutoSize = true;
        this.label2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
        this.label2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(76, 37);
        this.label2.Name = "label2";
        this.label2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(66, 13);
        this.label2.TabIndex = 2;
        this.label2.Text = "ashleytechie";
        this.label2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.label2_Click);
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(listBox1);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.panel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 4, 3, 4);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 348);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 3;
        // 
        // listBox1
        // 
        listBox1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))), ((int)(((byte)(64)))));
        listBox1.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.None;
        listBox1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 9F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        listBox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
        listBox1.FormattingEnabled = true;
        listBox1.ItemHeight = 15;
        listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {
        "Jake Simpson",
        "Adam Jones",
        "Jane Peters",
        "Ashley Smith",
        "Sam Smith",
        "Joe Phelan",
        "Peter Black",
        "Tracy Bratford",
        "Jamie Harrison",
        "Peter Slims"});
        listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 107);
        listBox1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 4, 3, 4);
        listBox1.Name = "listBox1";
        listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(144, 180);
        listBox1.TabIndex = 3;
        listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged);
        // 
        // label3
        // 
        this.label3.AutoSize = true;
        this.label3.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 14.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.label3.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Window;
        this.label3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 79);
        this.label3.Name = "label3";
        this.label3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(105, 24);
        this.label3.TabIndex = 4;
        this.label3.Text = "Contact List";
        // 
        // panel2
        // 
        this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(205, 7);
        this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
        this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(518, 335);
        this.panel2.TabIndex = 4;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
        this.button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(16, 304);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(170, 31);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 5;
        this.button1.Text = "Edit Profile";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // Inside
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ButtonHighlight;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(730, 347);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
        this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
        this.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3, 4, 3, 4);
        this.Name = "Inside";
        this.Text = "Inside";
        this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Inside_Load);
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
        this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.panel1.PerformLayout();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
    public static System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Label label3;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
    private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;

}
}
```

Comment: `do not modify the contents of this method with the code editor.`  why not create a method to allow the data to be passed and leave the forms alone?

Comment: Can you tell me how I could do this please?

Comment: If you find yourself ever needing to change the designer file, then its a 100% guarantee you are doing something wrong.

Comment: I agree with @icemanind on this one, but change it to be 99.9%. There have been times that the designer gets messed up and I've had to manually clean up some code in there for the designer to be happy and start working with it again.

Comment: I'd even lower what @icemanind said down to 90%. I've had *many* controls not serializing as properly as they should (specially when doing visual form inheritance with collection properties) and had to fix .Designer.cs files manually way more times than I wished.

Answer (score 2):

Change this back to what it was previously: *(public to private, remove static)*

```
public static System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
```

Add this in the code-behind in your Form: *(you don't need a setter since you won't be creating a new ListBox from the other Forms... I hope)*

```
public ListBox MyListBox
{
    get { return listBox1; }
}
```

Now in other Forms (assuming they're being created by some process in your *first* Form), you'll pass a reference to the current instance of your Form with the ListBox on it, so you can actually access the public property you just created:

```
public class SecondForm : Form
{
    public SecondForm(FirstForm firstForm)
    {
        // do something with firstForm.MyListBox
    }
}
```

Lastly, I'd say be careful how much you do this. Forms being able to access each other's controls seems messy to me. If you added more details about exactly what you're trying to accomplish with this, we might be able to provide a better alternative.

Comment: `public MyListBox` is invalid code (no type defined, should be `public ListBox MyListBox`)... but even if it wasn't, what'd be the problem on having the original `listbox1` public if he is to access it via the instance? No need to create extra properties for that (if anything, I'd create a property for the listbox property you want to access, but definitely but not for the listbox itself).

Comment: Well, except for the fact that in the example it'd be named `listBox1`, I don't see why there should be a greater reason to rename a control than there would be to rename a property (one must assume that controls are generally members of the class you are defining, and follow the same method you'd follow with any other class members). And yes: the second part of your comment is definitely the way to go

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you changed the code in the designer file so that `listBox1` is now static. You can't do this because the designer must be able to instantiate an instance of `ListBox`.

What it sounds like you are trying to do is you are trying to modify the listbox from another form. The proper way you should do this is through properties. In your code (not the designer code, but the code behind code), have something like this:

```
public ListBox MyListBox
{
    get 
    {
        return listBox1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't change anything in the `.Designer.cs` file. If you want to change access modifiers you should do so through the Properties window.

That being said, your `public` change was fine, you just can't make it `static`. For the designer to function all the controls in the form must be independent to each instantiation.

```
// what the code will look like when you change it from the Properties window
public System.Windows.Forms.ListBox listBox1;
```

If you were to make the `ListBox` `static`, you would access it like

```
ListBox listbox = Inside.listBox1;
```

which doesn't make much sense if you have more than one `Inside` form floating around. If you make it non-`static` you can still access it from wherever you want as long as you have an instance of the `Inside` class.

```
Inside inside = new Inside();
ListBox listbox = inside.listBox1;
```

Comment: I still can't access it in other forms with just public, should I be able to?

Comment: @AshSmith Yes, but you have to access it from an instance of your form.

Comment: No, you should never touch the .Designer.cs file.

Comment: I said don't touch the file - I didn't say don't touch the Property grid.